# How to pass a pointer from unique_ptr to another object and manage the lifespan?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm sure there's a standard way to solve this problem, but I can't find it.

I have a `Processor` class which manages the lifespans of all objects. A `Foo` may be assigned to a `Bar` occasionally. But `Bar` needs to know when `Foo` is no longer available (has been removed by the `Processor`). What is the right way to achieve this?

```
class Processor {
  private:
    vector<unique_ptr<Foo>> foos;
    vector<unique_ptr<Bar>> bars;
};

class Bar {
  public:
    void AssignFoo(Foo* foo){ cur_foo = foo; }
  private:
    Foo* cur_foo = nullptr;
};
```

One option I can think of is to have a `map` in `Processor` which keeps track of the assignments, and have a function `RemoveFoo` in `Bar` but I'm wondering if there's any other way.

Comment: Seems std::shared_ptr and std::weak_ptr is the way to go.

Comment: This feels like what you want is actually a `std::unique_ptr<Foo> const*` instead of a `Foo*` inside `Bar`. This preserves your current ownership semantics. Using a `shared_ptr`, by contrast, doesn’t.

Comment: @KonradRudolph bad idea. the `unique_ptr`s are stored in a vector, so their address may change (and sharing `unique_ptr` without transferring ownership is bad design in my opinion)

Comment: @KonradRudolph-I agree with fdan. There are lots of posts online that suggest not to pass pointers or references to unique_ptr.

Comment: @PlastyGrove And these people are usually right. Except in your case you’ve explicitly added the requirement that `Bar` needs to be aware of the ownership so you can’t get around this (except by changing the ownership semantics, i.e. by *changing* your requirements).

Comment: @fdan I agree that it’s bad design but that’s OP’s stated requirement; if the requirements can be changed then a better solution might exist (but it’s not necessarily to use `shared_ptr`s). As for invalidating the pointers, that’s solvable by either using a different container with stable addresses, or by using a fixed-size container.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - To be honest, the only thing I need is to reset the pointer to `Foo` to `nullptr` when `Bar` is no longer available. Does that require knowledge of ownership? I'm also open to alternative approaches to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @PlastyGrove It depends on the actual use-case, but your last comment clearly implies that `Bar` owns the `Foo` objects — and `Processor` may *not* actually own them at all.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Sorry for the confusion. When I mean pointer to `Foo`, I mean `cur_foo`. `Processor` is the one that decides when to remove the `Foo` objects from the vector and invalidate them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is using `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`:

```
class Processor {
private:
    vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> foos;
    vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> bars;
};

class Bar {
public:
    void AssignFoo(const std::weak_ptr<Foo>& foo){ cur_foo = foo; }
private:
    bool FooIsValid() const {
        return !cur_foo.expired();
    }  

    std::weak_ptr<Foo> cur_foo;
};
```

EDIT: tried earlier to use `unique_ptr` and raw pointers but it turn out wrong from the beginning so I removed it.

Comment: @bartop It still breaks if `Processor` removes an `unique_ptr` instead of only resetting it (even if you fix the error in `&(*foo)`).

Comment: @bartop - Thanks, I'll give your first method a try. I'm not sure about the second one though, all the posts I see online suggest that it's not a good idea to pass a `const &` to `unique_ptr`

Comment: @bartop - I presume we can also use `!cur_foo.expired()` in the `FooIsValid` function?

Comment: This shouldn't even compile, as `&(*foo)` is of type `Foo*` and not `Foo**`